# Blender 4.0 not running on 'Cintiq Companion 2'

Tags: error

After updating to Blender 4.0 it can't run anymore on an Cintiq Companion2.

It worked great with Blender 3.6.5.

The detailed specifications of the Cintiq Companion 2 are as follows:

・Processor: 5th Generation Broadwell Core i7-5557U processor, 3.1 GHz
・Graphics: Intel Iris graphics 6100 (OpenGL 4.3)
・Storage: 512GB (SSD)
・RAM: 16GB (DDR3)